# Get the Type (T) of a Nullable<T> at runtime?

Tags: c#, nullable

I don't really know what to add to the title, I'd like to get the Type (T) of a Nullable.
For example, I got a an object whose Type is Nullable and I'd like to get something like "System.Int32" (the type of course, not the string)

Comment: I believe this is a dupe but can't find it, but you're looking for [Nullable.GetUnderlyingType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.nullable.getunderlyingtype.aspx). Could be http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5174423/getting-basic-datatype-rather-than-weird-nullable-one-via-reflection-in-c-sha or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5181494/determine-if-a-generic-param-is-a-nullable-type

Comment: http://blog.dotnetclr.com/archive/2008/03/11/get-underlying-type-from-a-nullable-type.aspx

Comment: The question is ambiguous. Do you have a Type object representing a nullable value type, and you want to know the underlying value type? Or do you have an *instance* of an object of nullable value type and you want to know the underlying value type? The answers to those two questions are completely different. In the first case, you can use GetUnderlyingType. In the second case, either the object instance is boxed or it is not. If it is boxed then *it is not of nullable type*. There is no such thing as a boxed nullable value type. If it is not boxed then *you already know its type*.

Comment: I had a type representing the object. For an instance, I would have to use Activator.CreateInstance which could be possible but kinda useless imo, since I can get what i want from the Type !

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this : [Nullable.GetUnderylingType(myType)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.nullable.getunderlyingtype.aspx)

FYI : myType must be a Type

Comment: Wow, didn't know this existed, very nice!

Comment: got the following error :
Error 1 'System.Nullable' does not contain a definition for 'GetUnderylingType'

Comment: My test shows that Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(new Nullable<int>(2)) return null.
But using GetType() will work, see my answer below.

Comment: Are you referecing using System; ?

Comment: yep, System.Nullable.GetUnderylingType(...). Anyway, the other answer worked like a charm :)

Comment: Yes. Nullable.GetUnderlyingType has been added with .Net 2.0. I recommand you use this Method to get your underlyingType. Its cleaner

Answer (score 2):

This method should do the trick:

```
Type GetValueType(Type t)
{
   return t.GetGenericArguments().First();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use GetType() it works as (un)expected.

```
if (typeof(int?) == typeof(int))
    MessageBox.Show("It works with definitions");
if (new Nullable<int>(2).GetType() == typeof(int))
    MessageBox.Show("It works with instances!");
```

This sample code will show the last message box.
GetType() will return the underlying type.

Answer (score 0):

A Nullable is a Generic construction, so you should get it from the GenericArguments from the type, like this: `typeof(T).GetGenericArguments()[0]`

Answer (score 0):

```
System.Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(typeof(Nullable<int>));
```

Comment: This will throw NullReferenceException if myInt is currently null.

Answer (score 0):

Warning: horrible code, no checks, just an example etc:

```
using System;

static class Program {

    public static void Main(params string[] args) {
        Type t = typeof(int?);
        Type genericArgument = t.GetGenericArguments()[0];
        Console.WriteLine(genericArgument.FullName);
    }
}
```