# Get PropertyType.Name in reflection from Nullable type

Tags: c#, reflection, nullable

I  want use reflection for get properties type.
this is my code

```
var properties = type.GetProperties();
foreach (var propertyInfo in properties)
{
     model.ModelProperties.Add(
                               new KeyValuePair<Type, string>
                                               (propertyInfo.PropertyType.Name,
                                                propertyInfo.Name)
                              );
}
```

this code `propertyInfo.PropertyType.Name` is ok but if my property type is `Nullable` i get this `Nullable'1` string and if write `FullName` if get this stirng `System.Nullable1[[System.DateTime, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]`

Comment: Is it a Nullable<DateTime>?

Comment: And which is the string that you want to get? It looks like you will have to use the properties/methods on PropertyType that allows you to access the generic parameters of the type.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5174423/getting-basic-datatype-rather-than-weird-nullable-one-via-reflection-in-c-sha

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/401824/1174942). It creates a readable name for both generic and non-generic types (`System.Nullable<System.Int32>` for example).

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Change your code to look for nullable type, in that case take PropertyType as the first generic argument:

```
var propertyType = propertyInfo.PropertyType;

if (propertyType.IsGenericType &&
        propertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>))
    {
      propertyType = propertyType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
    }

model.ModelProperties.Add(new KeyValuePair<Type, string>
                        (propertyType.Name,propertyInfo.Name));
```

Answer (score 12):

This is an old question, but I ran into this as well.  I like @Igoy's answer, but it doesn't work if the type is an array of a nullable type.  This is my extension method to handle any combination of nullable/generic and array.  Hopefully it will be useful to someone with the same question.

```
public static string GetDisplayName(this Type t)
{
    if(t.IsGenericType && t.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>))
        return string.Format("{0}?", GetDisplayName(t.GetGenericArguments()[0]));
    if(t.IsGenericType)
        return string.Format("{0}<{1}>",
                             t.Name.Remove(t.Name.IndexOf('`')), 
                             string.Join(",",t.GetGenericArguments().Select(at => at.GetDisplayName())));
    if(t.IsArray)
        return string.Format("{0}[{1}]", 
                             GetDisplayName(t.GetElementType()),
                             new string(',', t.GetArrayRank()-1));
    return t.Name;
}
```

This will handle cases as complicated as this:

```
typeof(Dictionary<int[,,],bool?[][]>).GetDisplayName()
```

Returns:

```
Dictionary<Int32[,,],Boolean?[][]>
```