# Entity Framework: Get the DataType of Metadata IProperty

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

How do I find the DataType of Metadata.IProperty in Entity Framework Core?

```
var tableType = _dbContext.Model.GetEntityTypes().First(c => c.GetTableName() == tableName);
foreach (var property in tableType.GetProperties())
{
     var test = property.PropertyInfo.PropertyType.Name;
```

Using `property.PropertyInfo.PropertyType.Name`, sometimes works, however for nullable objects it prints null. I am looking for a clean way to get data type.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Type` of the `IProperty` is represented by `ClrType` property. It handles correctly both real properties (having `PropertyInfo`), fields (EF Core 5.0+ [allow mapping fields](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-5.0/whatsnew#model-building-for-fields) as properties), and also [shadow properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/shadow-properties) which have no assocaited `PropertyInfo` or `FieldInfo` at all.

```
var tableType = _dbContext.Model.GetEntityTypes().First(c => c.GetTableName() == tableName);
foreach (var property in tableType.GetProperties())
{
    Type type = property.ClrType;
}
```

Now speaking about string representation of that `Type`, it is arbitrary (similar any formatting) and depends on your needs. For instance, for debug display purposes EF Core internally uses the [`ShortDisplayName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.infrastructure.typeextensions.shortdisplayname?view=efcore-5.0) method. You can eventually use it, but note that it uses C# built-in types (e.g. `int` instead of `Int32`) and formats nullable type as "Nullable<{TypeName}>" e.g.

Requires

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure;
```

and then

```
var tableType = _dbContext.Model.GetEntityTypes().First(c => c.GetTableName() == tableName);
foreach (var property in tableType.GetProperties())
{
    var type = property.ClrType;
    var typeName = type.ShortDisplayName();
}
```

Again, converting `Type` to `string` differs, and depends on what this string will be used for. So use `Type` instead of `string` where possible. `GetColumnType` is different - it returns string because there is no class similar to `Type` to represent the database provider types.

Comment: Do you happen to know how to get the _value_ of the given IProperty without GetPropertyInfo ?? GetFieldInfo ?? ... ? Is there an EF-optimized "official" way?

Comment: Found `GetGetter().GetValue(entity)`, hope that it isn't reflection-based.

Comment: @BorisB. It is the one you've found. And no worry, they are using onetime compiled lambda delegates.

Answer (score 0):

You may look for this:[Get PropertyType.Name in reflection from Nullable type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14910584/14717050)

```
var propertyType = propertyInfo.PropertyType;

if (propertyType.IsGenericType &&
        propertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>))
    {
      propertyType = propertyType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
    }

model.ModelProperties.Add(new KeyValuePair<Type, string>
                        (propertyType.Name,propertyInfo.Name));
```

Comment: I just tried propertyInfo.PropertyType.Name, and sometimes it gives me a null, I am writing to fix that

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already using `PropertyType.Name`, I'm assuming that you are expecting a string denoting the name of the types, and not more information about the types.

1. You can use `IProperty.ClrType` to get the data type of an `IProperty`
2. You can detect nullability of a type with `Nullable.GetUnderlyingType()`
3. Nullable types are basically generic types, [`Nullable<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.nullable-1?view=net-5.0), so you can obtain the type arguments with `Type.GenericTypeArguments` property

Combining the facts above you can create an extension method like -

```cs
public static string GetPropertyType(this IProperty property)
{
    return Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(property.ClrType) != null
        ? nameof(Nullable) + "<" + property.ClrType.GenericTypeArguments.First().Name + ">"
        : property.PropertyInfo.PropertyType.Name;
}
```

Now, nullable or not, you can get a "clean" string for the data type name -

```cs
var tableType = _dbContext.Model.GetEntityTypes().First(c => c.GetTableName() == tableName);
foreach (var property in tableType.GetProperties())
{
     var test = property.GetPropertyType();
}
```